# MATLAB: dsolve not giving solution

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, dsolve

I am trying to solve a 4th order differential equation with boundary conditions but function `dsolve` is not giving solution. It is running for more than an hour. The code I have made is

```
syms omega delta x f(x)
df(x) = diff(f);
dff(x) = diff(df);
dfff(x) = diff(dff);
S = dsolve(diff(f,4) + 2*delta*diff(f,3) + delta^2*diff(f,2)...
- omega^2*f == 0, f(0) == 0, df(0) == 0, dff(1) == 0, dfff(1) == 0);
```

Is their any alternate method to find its non-trivial solution?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that this system with arbitrary parameters and arbitrary `f(x)` has an analytic solution?

Comment: yes, the above mentioned equation and its solution is published in a journal papar

Comment: Also, it is an equation for a cantilever beam where f(x) is its deflection which cannot be equal to zero for all x

Comment: Then you should edit your question to provide a link to this paper.